# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, runtime, castor

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

    at org.exolab.castor.mapping.Mapping.loadMappingInternal(Mapping.java:474)

    at org.exolab.castor.mapping.Mapping.loadMappingInternal(Mapping.java:436)

    at org.exolab.castor.mapping.Mapping.loadMapping(Mapping.java:363)

    at com.hoc.ejems2.client.util.bean.XMLJavaBeanMapping.initialize(XMLJavaBeanMapping.java:61)
```

I am getting the above error when trying to acces the castor jar.

Comment: You'll have to elaborate a little bit. What are you doing?

Comment: Please edit your question to display the stacktrace correctly.
Moreover we are missing important information here : What is the method that is missing ? The `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` should display the missing method name (at least)

Comment: i am trying to load the read the xml file

Comment: I am not getting any method name.

Comment: actually we have shifted the server on cloud which runs on windows server 2008, previously it used to run perfectly with same code on server 2003.

Comment: This most likely means that you are running your program with a different version of the Castor library than what you compiled it with. Make sure you use the same versions when compiling and running.

Comment: Thanks alot guys, actually had missed to add it in the calsspath (castor.xml).

Answer (score 1):

What version of castor (or castor-xml) are you using? Maybe do you need to upgrade library to newer version?

Or is it possible that your castor libary is conflicting with other versions of castor library in your server?